# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'g.ThemeColors.light') in react native, expo.io

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I am learning react native and working on expo.io, as stackNavigation in react native has been changed and I changed it accordingly in my code but it gives me following error:

```
Device: (970:881) undefined is not an object (evaluating 'g.ThemeColors.light')
Evaluating module://react-navigation-stack.js
Evaluating module://App.js.js
Loading module://App.js
```

This is my app.js code is basically navigation through screens.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  View,
  StyleSheet,

} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
// You can import from local files
import SignupView from './components/Screens/SignUpView';
import HomePage from './components/Screens/HomePage';
import SuperAdminHome from './components/Screens/SuperAdminHome';
import Departments from './components/Screens/Departments';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';



const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({

 //SplashView:{screen:Splash},
  HomePageScreen:{screen:HomePage},
  SignupScreen: { screen: SignupView },
  SuperAdminView:{screen:SuperAdminHome},
  DepartmentsView:{screen:Departments},

});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: it's best to refer to issues on the react-navigation repository for more information on question like this, see this search query specifically that matches the error you're seeing: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues?q=is%3Aissue+ThemeColors+is%3Aclosed

in each thread there are some solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can start to learn with expo snack working example:

https://snack.expo.io/@mehran.khan/navigation